# Add new column for next consecutive row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
    id  value
0    1      0
1    1    100
2    1    200
3    1    300
4    1      0
5    2      0
6    2    500
7    2    600
8    2      0
9    3      0
10   3    700
11   3      0
```

for every entry in value column i want to add new column which belongs to the next row entry in value column,

for eg:

```
     id  value   value2
0    1      0     100
1    1    100     200
2    1    200     300
3    1    300       0
4    2    0       500
5    2    500     600
6    2    600       0
7    3      0     700
8    3    700       0
```

Comment: Why are you dropping rows 4, 8, and 11 from the original dataframe.  These are all the last items in the group which happen to have zero values in the sample data.  Should we assume this can always be dropped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**
By using numpy instead of `pd.Series.shift` I avoid the insertion of `np.nan` and casting to `float`

```
df.groupby(
    'id', group_keys=False
).apply(lambda d: d.iloc[:-1].assign(value2=d.value.values[1:]))

    id  value  value2
0    1      0     100
1    1    100     200
2    1    200     300
3    1    300       0
5    2      0     500
6    2    500     600
7    2    600       0
9    3      0     700
10   3    700       0
```

---

**Option 2**
If all your `'id'` are lumped together, I can do an `np.roll` on the entire column and to a simple `groupby` afterwards.

```
df.assign(
    value2=np.roll(df.value.values, -1)
).groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.head, n=-1)

    id  value  value2
0    1      0     100
1    1    100     200
2    1    200     300
3    1    300       0
5    2      0     500
6    2    500     600
7    2    600       0
9    3      0     700
10   3    700       0
```

Comment: What is the advantage of avoiding NaNs? Is it just for the casting?

Comment: OP or others might want to preserve the integer dtype for whatever reasons.  And integer is what OP showed as expected result.  Integers are exact.  Float is not.

Comment: by this i am missing the row with value 0. i'e im getting combinations 100-200,200-300,500-600 and so on

Comment: @SRingne I see that I am getting your expected output exactly.

Comment: @SRingne If none of our answers are working for your actual data, we'll need a sample that can reproduce your issue and thus figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @piRSquared Yes, sorry my mistake, answer is spot on :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupby` and `shift`, followed by `dropna`.

```
df['value2'] = df.groupby('id').value.shift(-1)
df = df.dropna().astype(int)
df

    id  value  value2
0    1      0     100
1    1    100     200
2    1    200     300
3    1    300       0
5    2      0     500
6    2    500     600
7    2    600       0
9    3      0     700
10   3    700       0
```

Answer (score 3):

I try see problem another way - create output with original `df` from previous question with [`numpy.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html):

```
print (df)
   value  id
0    100   1
1    200   1
2    300   1
3    500   2
4    600   2
5    700   3

def f(x):
   return pd.DataFrame({'value1': np.append(x, 0), 'value2': np.append(0, x)})

df = df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(f).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  value1  value2
0   1     100       0
1   1     200     100
2   1     300     200
3   1       0     300
4   2     500       0
5   2     600     500
6   2       0     600
7   3     700       0
8   3       0     700
```

Comment: Good use of append

Comment: @jezrael nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like that:

```
n = 1
df["value2"] = df["value1"].tolist()[n:] + df["value1"].tolist()[:n]
```

here n is the shift amount in rows